# system cannot find path specified / file specified grafana

Tags: go, grafana, building

I've been trying to build grafana from its source code on windows by following the instructions [here](http://docs.grafana.org/project/building_from_source/#dependencies)

I am stuck and am failing to set the GOPATH path properly.
I set it to the default go directory in C:\myname but whenever I try to change to that directory using the command "cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/grafana/grafana" it says the system cannot find the specified path.
And even if I put the path manually and in the directory try to run "go run build.go setup" the system cannot find the file specified.

If someone could help me that'd be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a new empty folder:

```
mkdir C:\myFolder
cd C:\myFolder
set GOPATH=C:\myFolder
go get github.com/grafana/grafana
```

That should create a `src\github.com\grafana\grafana` folder, with the sources inside.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I did that and then tried 'go run build.go setup' but it still gives the same error of the system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @gunsimar first, it depend in which folder you are executing that command. Second, make sure the shell session you are in, when executing that command, does have `GOPATH` still set to `C:\myFolder`. Third, check first that `$GOPATH\src\github.com\grafana\grafana` does exists after `go get`.